# Как заправить на python код и получить текст в теге <p>?

Tags: python, html, парсер, теги

Вот код со страницы:

```
<p>Для этого используется потребительская корзина, в состав которой входят сотни наименований различных товаров и услуг (на данный момент – 558).</p>
<p>Её структура пересматривается ежегодно.</p>
<p><strong>Инфляция в России по годам: 1991 – 2023</strong> (данные Росстата, в процентах)<span id="more-29630"></span></p>
<p>1991г.  –  160,4</p>
<p>1992г.  –  2508,8</p>
<p>1993г.  –  840,0</p>
<p>1994г.  –  214,8</p>
<p>1995г.  –  131,6</p>
<p>1996г.  –  21,8</p>
<p>1997г.  –  11,0</p>
<p>1998г.  –  84,5</p>
<p>1999г.  –  36,6</p>
<p>2000г.  –  20,1</p>
<p>2001г.  –  18,8</p>
<p>2002г.  –  15,06</p>
<p>2003г.  –  11,99</p>
<p>2004г.  –  11,74</p>
<p>2005г.  –  10,91</p>
<p>2006г.  –  9,0</p>
<p>2007г.  –  11,87</p>
<p>2008г.  –  13,28</p>
<p>2009г.  –  8,8</p>
<p>2010г.  –  8,78</p>
<p>2011г.  –  6,1</p>
<p>2012г.  –  6,58</p><div class="tvwuh63fb58456dbc7"><br/>
<center><div id="adfox_164689919557083472"></div>
```

Нужно получить данные в

> <р>2010г.  –  8,78</р>

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1500277/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b5-p

Answer (score 1):

```
s="""<p>Для этого используется потребительская корзина, в состав которой 
входят сотни наименований различных товаров и услуг (на данный момент – 
558). 
</p>
<p>Её структура пересматривается ежегодно.</p>
<p><strong>Инфляция в России по годам: 1991 – 2023</strong> (данные 
 Росстата, в 
процентах)<span id="more-29630"></span></p>
<p>1991г.  –  160,4</p>
<p>1992г.  –  2508,8</p>
<p>1993г.  –  840,0</p>
<p>1994г.  –  214,8</p> 
...
"""
from lxml import etree
import re
p=etree.HTML(s)
r=p.findall('.//p')
for el in r:
    if re.match('.{4}г.*',str(el.text)):
        print(el.text)
```

Вывод:

```
1991г.  –  160,4
1992г.  –  2508,8
1993г.  –  840,0
1994г.  –  214,8
1995г.  –  131,6
1996г.  –  21,8
1997г.  –  11,0
1998г.  –  84,5
1999г.  –  36,6
2000г.  –  20,1
...
```